# How do I learn a simple cut-off value between 2 classes given one-dimensional data?

Tags: classification, python, scikit-learn

Given a set of data which consists of a single real number and a class, I want to find a value (i.e., the inflection point if we were talking about logistic regression) which would lie right at the boundary of the two classes. What is the simplest way to do this using scikit-learn?

Answer (score -1):

This depends on the classifier you are using. For classifiers like logistic regression, you can calculate this quantity, if you have a threshold defined (for example, saying that p=50% is your threshold). If the coefficients are in a vector B, you can to solve the equation $1/(1+e^{-Bx}))=threshold$ for x, and this gives the dividing point.

For more complex classifiers that might not be solvable, you can get a range of numbers (using numpy.arange) and run the classifier on each. The cutoff point is between the two points where the classification changed from one class to another.

Comment: Logistic regression is not a classifier.  It is a probability model.  And it is not intended to be used with thresholding.  To use a threshold you must demonstrate that the relationship between X and P(Y=1) is flat on either side of the threshold.  Otherwise the threshold will be meaningless not to mention not reproducible by others.